# Derivation of the time period of a damped simple pendulum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, friction, oscillators, string

I need to perform an experiment in my university where I verify the experimentally obtained time period of a damped simple pendulum with the derived theoretical result. The damping agent is a strong cylindrical magnet aligned below the mean position of the pendulum. A brass bob would be used and the eddy current generated should damp it. How do I go about getting the equation for the time period?[image]

This is what I've got so far

F(restoring) = -ks-bv
mgsinθ-bv=-k(Lθ)

k= (mgsinθ -bv)/Lθ
=(mgθ-bv)/Lθ

T=?

Comment: Welcome on Physics SE :) Please write your formulas out and explain them. Pictures are unwelcome because they can't be copied and can be messy on smaller screens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your force equation has incorrect terms.  You are trying to make it look like a spring by inserting a spring force, but the spring force here is gravity, so you already have gravity in there and don't need -ks. There are just two forces, -mgs/L and -b ds/dt.  Here s=L theta, taking the approximation sin(theta) = theta for small theta.  Once you clean up the force equation, you need to solve the differential equation, where v=L d/dt(theta) or v=ds/dt if you use s rather than theta as your independent variable.  Solutions for differential equations like that are available online, you are generally not expected to solve that yourself.  For example, look at 
http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/oscda.html, and notice there are several important ranges in the degree of damping that will give qualitatively different results, so you won't know which form to use until you do the experiment and find out which regime you are in.  I would expect "underdamped."

Comment: I've based my equations on what I've read on this page http://dev.physicslab.org/document.aspx?doctype=3&filename=oscillatorymotion_pendulumshm.xml

Comment: But you can see that your equations are different from those.  The way you interpreted the meaning of those equations is wrong, because you include both a spring force, -ks, and a gravity, mg sin theta.  Those are actually the same force here, not two different ones.  Replace sin theta by theta, when theta is small, and replace theta by s/L, if you want to use s as the distance along the arc and track that instead of theta.  In the equations I cited, they use x instead of s, but it's just a different letter.

Comment: Also, note that the lab writeup with those equations in it does not include damping, the -bv force.  So you got that from somewhere else.  You are correct that damping is -bv, which is also -b ds/dt, but this is a separate term from -ks and should never be combined with it.  There is no sense in including v, or ds/dt, in some kind of effective value of k, that's not the meaning of k.